# Saving find command output to variable

Tags: terminal, find, variable

I'm trying to save the find output to a variable in this manner:

```
a=find /Users/Downloads/DTI_allsites/subprojects/*/UII_0077 -name "dti_preprocessed" -type d
```

But I keep getting the following message:

-bash:

> /Users/Downloads/DTI_allsites/subprojects/UII_B/UII_0077:
>   is a directory

whenever I try to use the command, to echo the path using: 
     `echo $a`

I don't get anything saved in the variable.  How can I fix this?

Comment: @steeldriver actually no it's not. I tried to do as they did and it still doesn't work..

Comment: @hsayya You did `a=$(find <...>)` and it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Since `find` returns a list of file paths, you'd want to use an array variable. Since a file path can contain any character but NUL, you'd want to use `-print0` and split the result on NUL

With `bash4.4`+:

```
readarray -td '' list < <(find ... -print0)

so-something-with "${list[@]}"
```